# How to restart the game when pressed enter in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, monogame

If the following code allows the game to exit when pressed esc ..

```
if (gamePad.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed
    || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
{
    this.Exit();
}
```

Then this code should allow the game to restart when pressed enter...

```
if (gamePad.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed
    || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
{
    this.Reset(); //<< PROBLEM HERE!!
}
```

What do I put here? Because Reset is not the keyword for it... 
I'm a beginner so if this is so wrong and stupid I am  sorry.

Comment: This is actually not something that is built in, you need to code this.  You could do this by re-initializing all of your game objects, or re-use them and reposition/reset them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA does not have a built-in function to restart the game, so you will need to do this yourself. You could even write a function within the `Game` class so that you could actually call `this.Reset();`.

```
private void Reset() {
  // Reset all variables
  health = 100;
  score = 0;
  level = 1; // etc.
}
```

Obviously, the implementation will be different depending on the details of the game, but will include resetting the important variables like score, player position, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows-Only solution to ACTUALLY restart the game:

In the Program.cs main method, you're probably doing something like:

```
MyGame game = new MyGame();
game.Run();
```

The Run method is blocking, and will not return until the game exits. To restart the game you could simply have a global static variable that you set to false at the initialization of the game, and in your Enter-Clicked method sets to true. Then check on return of the Run method if that value is True, and if so, run the thing again. So basically:

```
do
{
   Program.ShouldRestart = false;
   MyGame game = new MyGame();
   game.Run();
}
while (Program.ShouldRestart);
```

and in your Enter-Clicked method:

```
Program.ShouldRestart = true;
this.Exit(); // Assuming 'this' is the instance of the game.
```

Keep in mind, this won't completely restart the whole process, so any static variables you have will maintain their current values between "restarts".

Hence, why you should avoid static variables as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this line:

```
gameStateManager.getLevel(1).LoadContent();
```

It may help you to achieve GAME RESTART, but I'm not 100% sure because I'm new as well.

Comment: Could you _copy-paste_ the code instead of using an image; it's much more simple.